# Hypermultiplet as BPS particles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, supersymmetry

In the third paragraph of page 7 of the paper [arxiv:1112.3984](http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.3984) it mentions that we form a basis out of hypermultiplets on the charge lattice $\Gamma$. My questions are:

1. In what sense do we form such a basis?
2. What does it mean that the BPS states are required to form a positive integral basis? (in a more general way than what is explained in the text)

Comment: there is an answer at http://physicsoverflow.org/33196